# How to get generic TreeView from implemented Node class?

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to C# programming. Currently, I am creating a small application related to OPC UA as my test project. I have created one class in c++ that printing a hierarchy of nodes i.e. Tree. That also works in C# console window 100%.

I would like to implement that Node hierarchy in C# TreeView of Windows Application Forms(WAF). I tried the solution form [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenode?view=netframework-4.8), but somehow due to recursion function, I got Error of "Infinity loop".

So, Could anyone help me to figure out?

[image]

```
foreach(Customer customer2 in customerArray)
{
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(customer2.CustomerName));

    // Add a child treenode for each Order object in the current Customer object.
    foreach(Order order1 in customer2.CustomerOrders)
    {
        treeView1.Nodes[customerArray.IndexOf(customer2)].Nodes.Add(
            new TreeNode(customer2.CustomerName + "." + order1.OrderID));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't a code writing service. You need to make a start on your code, and then come back here when you get stuck.

Comment: Provide some code to show what you've already tried.

Comment: Hi  David, I am asking for a hint, if possible.
thank you :)
@DavidG